# How to open TCP and UDP ports on Mac

Tags: ios, macos, tcp, sdk, udp

How can I open specific ports in order to use a SDK for a project?

I have already tried [netcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat), but it seems that you can only *listen* to a specific port or *open* a specific port if you have a *hosting* website.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are you asking how to get a server process listening on a particular port (if so, what kind of server software, etc), or how to prevent a firewall from blocking access to that port (in which case, what firewall, what's the network setup, etc)?

Answer (score 4):

To open a port and keep listening on it, on macOS this should be working:

```
nc -lk 8080
```

To test you can connect to the opened port by doing:

```
nc -vt 0 8080
```

To use [UDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol), you just need to use option `-u`, for example:

```
nc -u -lk 8080
```

To test you can connect:

```
nc -u -vt 0 8080
```

Output:

```
found 0 associations
found 1 connections:
     1: flags=82<CONNECTED,PREFERRED>
        outif (null)
        src 127.0.0.1 port 63214
        dst 127.0.0.1 port 8080
        rank info not available

Connection to 0 port 8080 [udp/http-alt] succeeded!
```